For a subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ under addition, and a subgroup of $G$, $H$, express $G/H$ as the direct sum of cyclic groups
$G$ is defined as $G = \left\langle \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix} \right\rangle$. For convenience let's call the four vectors that generate $G$, $g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4$ in that order.
Then $H$ is defined similarly as $H = \left\langle\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \right\rangle$. Similarly consider the four vectors to be $h_1, h_2, h_3, h_4$ in that order.
The goal of the problem is to describe $G/H$ as the direct sum of ciclic groups. Now the problem simply states that $G$ is generated by $g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4$, but it doesn't actually say how, so I initially approached the problem thinking that $G$ is generated in the group theory sense, aka, $G$ is the smallest subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^4$ that contains $g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4$. As it turns out all members of this group can be written as $G = \{Mg_1 + Ng_2 + Pg_3 + Qg_4 | M, N, P, Q \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. We can do the same for $H$ and we would get that $H = \{Mh_1 + Nh_2 + Ph_3 + Qh_4 | M, N, P, Q \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. We can find a more precise and succinct expression for $G$ and $H$, althought I am not 100% sure and haven't proved it yet, but I think $G = \left\{\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{bmatrix} | a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$, where $a, b, c, d$ all have the same parity, in other words, they either all end in $0.5$ after multiplying by the $\frac{1}{2}$ or they are all exact integers. We can do something similar for $H$ and we get $H = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{bmatrix} | a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ where $c$ has the same parity as $a+b+d$. From here I was just trying to find conditions under which $j_1,j_2 \in G$ would have $j_1H = j_2H$. However I wasn't ablet to finish this. I asked the teacher about it and he basically said something completely different from what I was doing.
Essentially the teacher said $G$ is generated by $g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4$ in the sense of span of the vectors, so $G$ is made up of every linear combination of the 4 vectors. But the 4 vectors $g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4$ are linearly independent and thus they span the whole set $\mathbb{R}^4$. Same for $H$. I pointed this out to the teacher and asked him if the point of the problem was then to write $\mathbb{R}^4/\mathbb{R}^4$ as the direct sum of cyclic groups, and he said no because $G$ and $H$ have a different basis, so it's different. But to me this makes no sense, the set of vectors that $G$ represents, regardless of what basis, is $\mathbb{R}^4$ and same for $H$, so their quotient would just be equal to $G/H = \mathbb{R}^4/\mathbb{R}^4 = \{\mathbb{R}^4\}$, is this not right? And then there is only one way to express $\{\mathbb{R}^4\}$ as the direct sum of cyclic groups, just express is as the sum of itself with itself. This doesn't seem to be the solution the teacher wants though, since he said we need to use this fact: $(G_1 \bigoplus G_2 \bigoplus...\bigoplus G_n)/(H_1 \bigoplus H_2 \bigoplus...\bigoplus H_n) = (G_1/H_1) \bigoplus (G_2/H_2) \bigoplus ...\bigoplus (G_n/H_n)$
Anyways, teacher said he already gave us enough hints and he refused to answer more questions, the entire class has no idea how to solve this problem, can you help me out? I'd really appreciate it.

You are right and your teacher is wrong. If it's the linear span then $G = H$ and the quotient is trivial. It makes more sense for it to be the $\mathbb Z$-span as you say. In this case this is a standard kind of problem about Smith Normal Form -- have you learned about that?

@SeanEberhard I haven't heard of SNF before, but if it helps solve the problem I'll do more research on it. Th Wikipedia page on SNF seems to talk about quite a few things we haven't seen in class yet. Do you happen to know a good reference (preferably a book) that explains SNF in detail?

Maybe a better idea for now is to press on with your own approach, which is basically sound and should get there in the end with a bit more work. But for your own information you should keep in mind that this is a special case of a very general method called SNF, which is covered by every book on basic module theory.

As mentioned in the comments, your teacher has made very misleading comments. If $G$ and $H$ are subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ then $G/H \cong \mathbb R^d$ where $d = \dim G - \dim H$, and in fact in this example $G = H = \mathbb R^n$ so $G/H$ is trivial. Good thing too, because if $G / H \cong \mathbb R^d$ for $d > 0$ then $G/H$ would be a pretty scary direct sum of cyclic groups. Never mind all this, it's the wrong interpretation, almost certainly.
Rather, you are on the right track with considering $G$ and $H$ to be just abelian groups generated by four elements each. In this case a general approach would be to express the generators of $H$ in terms of the generators of $G$, and then put the resulting matrix in Smith normal form. This method is explained by any text on basic module theory. It is a basic step in the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, or similarly in proving the rational canonical form (or Jordan normal form) theorem from linear algebra.
In your case, a practical suggestion is to continue with your current approach, which is fundamentally sound. Working out the details from scratch in a basic case should give you useful insight into the general situation.
Hints:

You happen to be right that (paraphrasing) $$G = \{(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb R^4 : a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z ~\text{or}~ a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z + 1/2\} \\ H = \{(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb Z^4 : a + b + c + d~\text{even}\}.$$ Now prove it.
In particular $H \le \mathbb Z^4 \le G$. Can you determine the indices $|G : \mathbb Z^4|$ and $|\mathbb Z^4 : H|$? Therefore what is $|G:H|$?
It follows that there are just ___ possibilities for the group $G/H$. You can distinguish between the possibilities by testing the order of some elements.

Good luck!

As commented by @SeanEberhard:

"You are right and your teacher is wrong."
"this is a standard kind of problem about Smith Normal Form".

You are given
$G=\Bbb Zg_1\oplus\Bbb Zg_2\oplus\Bbb Zg_3\oplus\Bbb Zg_4$ and $H=\Bbb Zh_1\oplus\Bbb Zh_2\oplus\Bbb Zh_3\oplus\Bbb Zh_4\subset G$, with
$$h_1=2g_1-g_2,\;h_2=-g_1+2g_2-g_3-g_4,\;h_3=-g_2+2g_4,\;h_4=-g_2+2g_3.$$
Following the algorithm for SNF leads to
$G=\Bbb Zg'_1\oplus\Bbb Zg'_2\oplus\Bbb Zg'_3\oplus\Bbb Zg'_4$ and $H=\Bbb Zh'_1\oplus\Bbb Zh'_2\oplus\Bbb Zh'_3\oplus\Bbb Zh'_4$, with
$$g'_1=2g_1-g_2,\;g'_2=3g_1-g_3-g_4,\;g'_3=g_4-g_1,\;g'_4=g_4$$
$$h'_1=h_1=g'_1,\;h'_2=h_2+2h_1=g'_2,$$$$h'_3=h_3-h_1=2g'_3,\;h'_4=h_1+2h_2+2h_3+h_4=2g'_4.$$
Therefore,
$$G/H=(\Bbb Zg'_1\oplus\Bbb Zg'_2\oplus\Bbb Zg'_3\oplus\Bbb Zg'_4)/(\Bbb Zg'_1\oplus\Bbb Zg'_2\oplus\Bbb Z(2g'_3)\oplus\Bbb Z(2g'_4))\cong(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2.$$
